# Latin Hypercube Sampling

Tags: probability-or-statistics, sampling

I'm looking into Mathematica and I can't find if there is an instruction or a set of them that can perform the [`Latin Hypercube Sampling`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling), given variable, their interval and possibly relation between them (like a always greater than b)

thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can enlighten the masses as to what Latin Hypercube Sampling is?!

Comment: Latin hypercube sampling is a statistical method for generating a sample of plausible collections of parameter values from a multidimensional distribution
When sampling a function of N variables, the range of each variable is divided into M equally probable intervals. M sample points are then placed to satisfy the Latin hypercube requirements; note that this forces the number of divisions, M, to be equal for each variable.
LHS ensures that the ensemble of random numbers is representative of the real variability

Comment: I am almost sure that there are LHS implementations for both Matlab and R –

Comment: Matlab definitely has it. I have not found anyone using Mathematica that has an LHS code. I checked Demonstrations. I'm thinking of writing one.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the next link:

https://sites.google.com/site/efialto/lhc_mathematica

I check the algorithm against the original source, it works!

Comment: Interesting. Glad someone thought to do this beforehand. Good Question!!

Comment: In 2022, the location has changed to [here](https://sites.google.com/site/efialto/mathematica/lhc_mathematica).